# embed audio and video in HTML or .aspx

Tags: html, asp.net

What is the Best way to embed audio and video files in .aspx pages. So that it works in all browsers?
 It also should play all type of audio files and video files with out using HTML 5.

Comment: Create your .aspx using HTML5

Comment: without using HTML 5

Comment: You can use the same code that I've just posted and place it where ever you want in you page to see if it will work

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example,just copy and paste it in note pad and save the file as name.html and run the page

```
<html>
      <video id="video1" width="420" controls>
        <source src="http://corrupt-system.de/assets/media/sintel/sintel-trailer.m4v" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="pjds.ogg" type="video/ogg"> 
      </video>
</html>
```

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18751612/html5-video-player-ie8-embed-fallback-vs-fixed-positioned-element